# Which is preferred System.out.print() or System.out.printf()?

Tags: java

The most common way I see output done to the console is:

```
System.out.print("..");
```

or

```
System.out.println(".."); // New Line
```

But now and again I come across this way:

```
int answer = 42;
System.out.printf("%2d is the answer.", answer);
```

I appreciate `printf` gives you more control of the formatting of the output. My question is, when should you use `printf` over the other options? And which is better practice/preferred?

Comment: If you need to format the output? Looks like you already answered your question.

Comment: printf is more closely related to c's printf function

Comment: Preferred by whom? This is just like asking: Which is preferred + or -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question actually demonstrates the preferred use cases: if you want to inject values into the text being printed (especially if you need specific formatting), then use `printf()`; otherwise, use `print()` or `println()`, depending on whether you want to append a line break at the end.

As an aside, if you want to insert a platform-dependent line break when using `printf()`, you can use the `%n` escape sequence.

Answer (score 2):

One big reason `printf` isn't as widely used is because it wasn't added until Java 1.5.

There is no best practice one way or the other, so use the one that best suits your needs.

Comment: I didn't know it was not added till 1.5. My degree course taught us 1.2 and that frustrated me, especially as the year was pro 2006.

Comment: 1.5 added generics, annotations and auto-boxing which are big things, so anything older than that is a pain.

Comment: I am currently learning Generics, any code that has it in currently baffles me.

Comment: Generics is great. I use it all the time, especially for collection types.